# Can I modify the contents of a params array?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have a bunch of methods which substitute values into a parametised URL and call this URL as a WebRequest. I pulled this into a utility method

```
public string BuildMethodCall(string MethodName, params object[] Args)
{
 ... //stuff
 String.Format(something, Args);
}
```

But I need to ensure all `DateTime` objects are formatted a certain way. To save me doing this in each calling method can I make `BuildMethodCall` modify the params elements somehow so each `DateTime dt` is replaced with `dt.ToString(format)`?

Comment: You could try it and see what happens. Or you could project a new array from the params argument and leave the original one untouched.

Comment: Maybe can you use an interceptor that do that for you in every request? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083559/where-and-how-to-use-interceptors-in-web-application

Comment: It seems little effort to actually try. Why didn't you write two lines of code to test this?

Comment: Inside the method there is nothing magical about the params array, it's just an array like any other. So yes, you can modify it. I would *try* to find a different way of doing things though as modifying the input array like that sounds fishy to me. But yes, you can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `params`-array is just a usual array as every other also. You may modify it´s entries as you want, but of course *not* its reference (as it´s not maked `out` or `ref`).

```
public string BuildMethodCall(string MethodName, params object[] Args)
{
    ... //stuff
    args[0] = String.Format(something, args[0]);
}
```

Now in your calling code use the new values:

```
@params = BuildMethodCall("DoSomething", @params);
foreach(var p in @params) 
{
    var dt = p as DateTime?;
    if(dt != null) ...
}
```

You could even re-reference the variable within your method:

```
public string BuildMethodCall(string MethodName, params object[] Args)
{
    ... //stuff
    args = // do something
}
```

However this has no effect at all to the calling code.

EDIT: Allthough the above works it´s not the best idea to change the semantics of an already introduced variable. You should consider to just add an array passed as `out` that contains the actual `DateTime`-instances and leave the input-values unchanged.

Comment: You can change the reference, but it has no effect on the calling method.

Comment: So basically iterate the array, use reflection to find which elements are `DateTime`, replace them with Strings.

Comment: @Mr.Boy there is no need for reflection. just try cast. `object as DateTime?` returns null if its not DateTime

Comment: Oh yeah... too easy to turn to reflection for every problem when it's not needed!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than monkey with the original array how about trying the following?

```
public string BuildMethodCall(string MethodName, params object[] Args)
{
    var newArgs = Args.Select(arg => arg is DateTime ? arg.ToString() : arg).ToArray();
    // New array has original arguments with date time arguments string formatted...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change the content but it could cause side effects 
A better way is to use a second array.
Code could look like this:

```
public string BuildMethodCall(string MethodName, params object[] Args)
{
  object[] tmpArgs = new object[Args.Length];
  for (int i = 0; i < Args.Length; i++)
  {
    if (Args[i].GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
    {
      tmpArgs[i] = ((DateTime)Args[i]).ToString();
    }
    else
      tmpArgs[i] = Args[i];
  }
  String.Format(something, tmpArgs);
}
```